# file browser in asp.net mvc3 aspx view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making web application in asp.net mvc3. and i made create,edit,delete controller corresponding views. In view table has image field. 
so i want file upload or file browser or input type file in-spite of text field

In table has also created On and modify On field. so i want this field take system time automatically.